# How can I retrieve data from a table and using a foreign key retrieve data from another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables : movies, schedule .

```
Schedule : schedule_id, movie_id, start_date, start_time ;

Movies: movie_id, movie_name, movie_description ;
```

I'm using php , and I want to retrieve every record in schedule `where start_date = 2014-11-14` which is quite simple but in the same query I want to get `movie_name` for every `movie_id` in schedule .

And if it's possible how will I access the result?

I used this before: `while($row = $rs->fetch_row())` but since I want data from 2 tables how will I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
$sql = "SELECT schedule.*, movies.movie_name FROM schedule JOIN movies ON schedule.movie_id = movies.movie_id WHERE schedule.start_data = '2014-11-14'";
```

You can leave the rest of your code like it is and $row will be ammended with the movie_name

Try researching MySQL JOIN on google ;)

Answer (score 1):

The query you want is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Schedule 
    INNER Movies ON Movies.movie_id = Schedule.movie_id 
WHERE Schedule.start_date = '2014-11-14';
```

You can access it using the same function that you were using